# Neovim's/Vim's "cursor()" not working after reading a file

Tags: vim, neovim

I have the following in my init.vim (the equivalent of .vimrc):

```
function Uva()
    :read /home/usr/.config/nvim/templates/file
    :call cursor(3,1)
endfunction
```

This function should read a file (which it does), and then move the cursor to line 3 column 1 (which it doesn't). If I run it and then manually execute the call cursor command the cursor does move, so I think it should be valid. I initially thought that my problem was that the original file didn't have enough lines, but it's not so. Even if I start with 100 lines the function doesn't work. Maybe the editor is too busy reading the file, but this is just a possibility.

Any ideas? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this work in Vim?  If so, I'd report it as a possible bug.

Comment: This looks like it should move to line 3 column 1. Why do you think it should go to line 26?

Comment: @FDinoff Right, it is supposed to move to line 3 (that was my mistake), but still it doesn't move at all.

Comment: @jszakmeister I just tried and it doesn't work in vim.

Comment: @Nonbeliever Works for me in both vim and neovim. The version of neovim I have is really old though. Make sure that it doesn't work with `vim -u NONE` first.

Comment: @FDinoff Thank you, now I know what happened. I defined a command in my init.vim as "command Uva exec Uva()" and it should have been "command Uva call Uva()". I found this out when i opened vim with -u NONE. Now it works for me.

Comment: @FDinoff, please post an answer so I can give you credit.

Comment: @Nonbeliever You should post the answer.

Comment: @FDinoff Ok. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function was correct, but I was calling it using

```
command Uva exec Uva()
```

and it should have been

```
command Uva call Uva()
```

Thanks to FDinoff for helping me.